# C++ Inheritance Question

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

In the file test.cpp, I have this:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  A(int a){};
  virtual ~A();

private:
};

class B : public A<int>
{
public:
  B(int a):A(a){};
  virtual ~B();

private:
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get this:

```
jason@jason-linux:~/Documents/ECLibrary$ g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp -o tdriver
test.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(int)’:
test.cpp:14: error: class ‘B’ does not have any field named ‘A’
test.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘A<int>::A()’
test.cpp:5: note: candidates are: A<T>::A(int) [with T = int]
test.cpp:3: note:                 A<int>::A(const A<int>&)
```

I do not want a default constructor for my base class, since it doesn't make sense in my code.  I just want my derived class to perform the called constructor of the base class and do some extra construction for the extra stuff in the derived class.  I'm really not sure why it is trying to call the default constructor of the base class when I'm trying to explicitly call an alternate constructor.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have implementation of class A constructor ?

Comment: Surely you saw how the post would look since you needed to scroll past the preview to submit. Read the editing FAQ and use the editing toolbar to edit your posts, not just guess. (Evident by `[code]` and whatnot.) You're just messing all the fixes other people are making, somehow completely skipping the preview every single time. I almost want to -1 just for that. Surely you don't approach every task this way?

Comment: What's that word `template` doing there? Anyway, please edit as follows: put the code on separate lines, select those lines, and click the format-as-code button (it has zeroes and ones on it). Cheers,

Comment: Seems to be fine to me. I don't actually have a compiler on hand, unfortunately, but it seems fine.

Comment: If you have trouble using the button, put your code within the HTML pre tag. It's a lot easier when the question is clear.

Comment: You deserve a -1 for not letting people edit your question into looking like it ought to.  It's bad enough posting a question without even bothering to figure out how to format it correctly, but undoing everyone else's attempts to help you?  No.

Comment: Who keeps unfixing it? This is the third time I've re-fixed it.

Comment: How many Stack Overflow contributors does it take to format this question correctly?  We're up to eight now... anyone want to try for nine?

Comment: @James: It's already at CW now, pretty fail. Edit history is hilarious, though.

Comment: @DeadMG - Oh, I see, he's not intentionally unfixing it.  He keeps editing various things about it and then saving the edit, then immediately editing it again.  So he never edits a fixed version.  At least, presuming Jason is a he.  :-)

Comment: @James: It usually helps when editing to separate code and logs.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I needed to have sstatic.net approved with noscript to see all of the edit options... I never saw a preview, or an ability to add special editing options.  I didn't know sstatic.net was needed since I can normally view stackoverflow fine without it.

Comment: @Jason:  No problem; now you know :-)  (And, welcome to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the template argument list to `A`:

```
B(int a) : A<int>(a) { }
```

Note that the code that you have--using `A` without the template argument list--is valid C++.  Comeau and Visual C++ 2010 both accept the code as-is.

g++ 4.3 does not accept the code without the template argument list.  Perhaps someone can test a later version of g++ or check the g++ bug database to see whether it is a known issue (I don't regularly use g++ and am not familiar with their bug database).

Comment: @Oli:  Good to know.  Perhaps someone here can test with a later version of g++ and/or check the g++ bug database.  I'm afraid I don't use g++ regularly enough to be familiar with it.

Comment: @Oli: OK, correct me if I am wrong, but I think that injected class names apply only if the class is a template, or if the base is dependent. So maybe this isn't a g++ bug after all? I may be completely wrong though...

Comment: @Armen: No, the injected class name can be used "whenever it is in scope" (C++03 14.6.1/2a, which also gives an example of using it in a derived class)

Answer (score 3):

Try `B(int a):A<int>(a){}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to read:

```
class B : public A<int>
{
public:
  B(int a):A<int>(a){};
  virtual ~B();

private:
};
```

and it will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to initialize your base class as `A`, but you don't derive from `A`, you derive from `A<int>`

Comment: The injected class name for a template can be used with or without the template argument list, so as long as `A` is unambiguous, you can use `A` and `A<int>` interchangeably (if you derived from two specializations of `A`, as in `class B : A<int>, A<float> { };`, then `A` would be ambiguous inside of `B` and you would have to use `A<int>` and `A<float>`, respectively).

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're trying to do explicit specialization of class A for integer.
Guess should be written as `template<> Class A<int>`...